# Stop pyquery inserting spaces where there aren't any in source HTML?

Tags: python, lxml, pyquery

I am trying to get some text from an element, using pyquery 1.2. There are no spaces in the displayed text, but pyquery is inserting spaces.

Here is my code:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
html = '<h1><span class="highlight" style="background-color:">Randomized</span> and <span class="highlight" style="background-color:">non-randomized</span> <span class="highlight" style="background-color:">patients</span> in <span class="highlight" style="background-color:">clinical</span> <span class="highlight" style="background-color:">trials</span>: <span class="highlight" style="background-color:">experiences</span> with <span class="highlight" style="background-color:">comprehensive</span> <span class="highlight" style="background-color:">cohort</span> <span class="highlight" style="background-color:">studies</span>.</h1>'
doc = pq(html)
print doc('h1').text()
```

This produces (note spaces before colon and period):

```
Randomized and non-randomized patients in clinical trials : 
experiences with comprehensive cohort studies .
```

How can I stop pyquery inserting spaces into the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading `PyQuery`'s [source](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/_modules/pyquery/pyquery.html#PyQuery.text) I found that the [`text()`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/api.html#pyquery.pyquery.PyQuery.text) method returns the following:

```
return ' '.join([t.strip() for t in text if t.strip()])
```

Which means that the content of non-empty tags will always be separated by a single space. I guess the problem is that the textual representation of html is not well-defined so I don't think it could be considered a bug--especially since the example in the `text()` documentation does exactly this:

```
>>> doc = PyQuery('<div><span>toto</span><span>tata</span></div>')
>>> print(doc.text())
toto tata
```

If you want another behavior, try implementing your own version of `text()`. You can use the original version for inspiration since it's only 10 lines or so.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. Curious that the pyquery approach is different from how most browsers choose to display text.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit funny. Note that just using an empty string as the separator will not really work either, since PyQuery strips the content of each tag as well. I think it's a bit of a shortcut. Instead it should join everything without separators and remove consecutive spaces the way HTML is usually rendered. Even the example code above is rendered as "tototata" in most (all?) browsers.